# Do World customizations affect the seed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, you can build a world using a World Seed. Using this seed, you ca recreate this world over and over again.

However, there are things that affect this. For example, using a seed from an earlier version of Minecraft (e.g., prior to biome additions like mesa and savannah), the seed will generate a different world.

Is this the same for a "customised" world? I recently created a world in where I ramped up the dungeon spawn rate to max. If I recreated the world using the world seed, but with less dungeons, will the world be the same?

What can affect the world generation using a world seed in the customisation options?

Comment: My gut says that since dungeon placement happens after terrain generation, the world will look the same, but dungeons will be placed differently. (Note that you wouldn't just be missing dungeons -- they should all appear in different locations, except perhaps the first one to be placed!) After all, the seed is really just the seed for the pRNG.

Comment: @Schism I agree, there would be things you can change that shouldn't affect the generation, like vein sizes etc, but then there are some things you can change like lava lakes, and Biome sizes that definitely would change the way the world is generated, even if you used the same seed. Since dungeons are underground there's a possibility that it shouldn't affect the seed, but I'd like to know for sure, as well as what does, and what doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, dungeons and other structures are generated *after* the rest of the world, so you would indeed see the same world, just with an increase of dungeons inside it.

Comment: What can affect the world generation in the customization options?

Comment: Things that effect the world :P So anything that will effect biome type, heights, ocean rarity etc.